# Number of RSS Articles from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rss

Does anyone know how to get the total number of articles from an RSS feed served by Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, to get to know (& even edit the value) that how many number of RSS articles/posts are being served via RSS feed by your WordPress site, in the **Dashboard:: Settings -> Reading**

Third settings is which specify the RSS items number which is labeled as: **"Syndication feeds show the most recent ---"**